Keyvalue pipe gives wrong return type
I'm looking at this overload in the KeyValuePipe doc:
@param input: Record<K, V> | ReadonlyMap<K, V>
@param compareFn: ((a: KeyValue<K, V>, b: KeyValue<K, V>) => number) | null | undefined
@returns KeyValue<K, V>[]

My code:
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="item.teamId">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of lookups.teams | keyvalue" [value]="option.key">
    {{ option.value }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>

lookups.teams has the type Record<number, string | undefined>. so I expected option to be KeyValue<number, string | undefined> according to the docs. However, it turns out to be KeyValue<string, string | undefined>
I need option.key to be a number for ngModel to work. How can I fix it?

I was confused by the overload definition. If the input is Record type, the key of the output is always string.
From source:
  /*
   * NOTE: when the `input` value is a simple Record<K, V> object, the keys are extracted with
   * Object.keys(). This means that even if the `input` type is Record<number, V> the keys are
   * compared/returned as `string`s.
   */


Record<number, string | undefined> is essentially an object in Javascript, and object keys in Javascript are always coerced into strings.
For example:
const obj: Record<number, string> = { 1: 'one', 2: 'two' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ['1', '2']

The keyvalue pipe relies on Object.entries() or similar mechanisms internally, which returns keys as strings even if they were originally numbers.
To ensure that option.key is treated as number, you can explicitly convert it using + operator or Number() function.
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="item.teamId">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of lookups.teams | keyvalue" [value]="+option.key">
    {{ option.value }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>

